# Setting OS Flag to test OS specific features

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

Why doesn't this work (It's failing the assert...that I don't want it to execute)?

```
#define OS_MACOSX 0

#if defined(OS_MACOSX)
    fructose_assert(1==2);
#endif
```

Comment: You define something, then check if it is defined, and wonder why that yields true? I don't get why you are confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're using the wrong test.

`OS_MACOSX` IS defined... to `0`.  You asked if it is *defined*.  Ask instead if it is *set*:

```
#if OS_MACOSX
    fructose_assert(1==2);
#endif
```

If it is defined to something that evaluates to zero, or not defined at all, the `#if` will skip over the code.  Any non-zero value, and the `#if` condition is met and the code is compiled.

See this related question: [Why do people use #ifdef for feature flag tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21272744/103167)